# How to find all input tags and submit buttons from all opened windows using Selenium Ruby?

Tags: ruby, windows, browser, selenium, input

I want to scan all opened browser windows for input tags and submit buttons.
I have opened all these windows by grabbing links from loaded page.
My code is following.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
page = driver.get " http://testasp.vulnweb.com "
link = Array.new(driver.find_elements(:tag_name, "a"))
link.each do |a|
    a = driver.execute_script("var d=document,a=d.createElement('a');a.target='_blank';a.href=arguments[0];a.innerHTML='.';d.body.appendChild(a);return a", a)
    a.click
end
i = driver.window_handles
```

I am able to get all opened window IDs.
How I can find input elements from all these opened browser windows and also submit buttons and forms?
`window_handles` does not accept any arguments when I tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch to the popups, you would use:

```
driver.switch_to().window(handle)
```

So could do something like this:

```
#Get all of the window handles
i = driver.window_handles

#Iterate through the popups
#Note that starting at index 1 assuming we do not care about the original window
i[1..i.length].each do |handle|
    #Switch to popup
    driver.switch_to().window(handle)

    #Do whatever processing you want on the popup
    #Example, get the number of input fields
    inputs = driver.find_elements(:tag_name, 'input')
    puts inputs.length

    #Probably want to close the popup   
    driver.close
end

#Switch back to the original window
driver.switch_to().window(i[0])

#Do whatever processing you want on the original window
puts driver.title
```

Answer (score 0):

I used following code, its helped me to open each link in new tab.

```
@driver.get "http://thiyagarajan.wordpress.com/"
  link = @driver.find_elements(:tag_name, "a")
  link.each do |a|
    a = @driver.execute_script("var d=document,a=d.createElement('a');a.target='_blank';a.href=arguments[0];a.innerHTML='.';d.body.appendChild(a);return a", a)
    a.click
  end
```